# Programmatically fireEvent in TextField - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Let's say a have a TextField

```
TextField tf = new TextField();
```

and I want to simulate the user pressing a key.

```
KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, 
    KeyCode.A.toString(), KeyCode.A.toString(), 
    KeyCode.A, false, false, false, false);
tf.fireEvent(ke);
```

if I examine the text contents of tf, I will see this state hold true

```
tf.getText() == ""
```

What happened to my KeyEvent and why didn't the text equal "a"? I have tried this with KEY_RELEASED, KEY_PRESSED, and KEY_TYPED

Contained Example:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;

import org.junit.rules.TestRule;
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runners.model.Statement;

public class TextFieldExample {

    @Rule public JavaFXThreadingRule javafxRule = new JavaFXThreadingRule();
    @Test
    public void onlyAcceptValidInputs() {
        TextField tf = new TextField();
        KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, 
                KeyCode.A.toString(), KeyCode.A.toString(), 
                KeyCode.A, false, false, false, false);
        tf.fireEvent(ke);
        Assert.assertEquals("A", tf.getText());
    }
}

class JavaFXThreadingRule implements TestRule {    
    /**
     * Flag for setting up the JavaFX, we only need to do this once for all tests.
     */
    private static boolean jfxIsSetup;

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement statement, Description description) {

        return new OnJFXThreadStatement(statement);
    }

    private static class OnJFXThreadStatement extends Statement {

        private final Statement statement;

        private OnJFXThreadStatement(Statement aStatement) {
            statement = aStatement;
        }

        private Throwable rethrownException = null;

        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable {

            if(!jfxIsSetup) {
                setupJavaFX();

                jfxIsSetup = true;
            }

            final CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        statement.evaluate();
                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        rethrownException = e;
                    }
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                }});

            countDownLatch.await();

            // if an exception was thrown by the statement during evaluation,
            // then re-throw it to fail the test
            if(rethrownException != null) {
                throw rethrownException;
            }
        }

        protected void setupJavaFX() throws InterruptedException {
            final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);            
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // initializes JavaFX environment
                    new JFXPanel();                    
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            });

            latch.await();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me (the text is actually `"A"`, not `"a"`, of course) with `KEY_TYPED`. Why would you want to do this though?

Comment: Hmm. This does not work for me, obviously, or I wouldn't have posted. I'm unit testing some classes I've written which limit the valid inputs to TextField.

Comment: Why don't you post a [MCVE]. (Though, assuming you're using a `TextFormatter`, you should really be unit testing the filter, otherwise you are integration testing JavaFX itself...)

Comment: Updated original post to include

Comment: Maybe the event if only processed if the text field is part of a live scene, though I am guessing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the text field is listening for `KEY_TYPED` events. Note that for `KEY_TYPED` events, the [text](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getText--) should be the empty string, and the [code](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html#getCode--) should be `KeyCode.UNDEFINED`.

Note also that in your test case, the text field is never added to a live scene. Because of this, it doesn't install its skin, which contains the logic for actually processing events. So you need to force the installation of the skin by calling `setSkin(...)`, passing in the result of the *protected* method `createDefaultSkin()`:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFieldFireEvent extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextField tf = new TextField() {
            {
                setSkin(createDefaultSkin());
            }
        };

        Button button = new Button("A");
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            KeyEvent ke = new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED, 
                    "a", "", 
                    KeyCode.UNDEFINED, false, false, false, false);
                tf.fireEvent(ke);
                System.out.println(tf.getText());
        });
        VBox root =new VBox(10, /*tf,*/ button);

        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 400));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, if this all seems to work fine for you, then perhaps that testing rule I found doesn't work for everything. Using identical code in my test case did not produce the desired result. I'll have to find another way to unit test this class.

Comment: @Derek In your test code, no skin is ever installed on the text field, so no events are not processed. You could of course consider just calling `appendText(..)`, or something similar, or see update for a hackaround.

Comment: adding the skin did not seem to work either. You seem to have a fair bit of knowledge about the inner workings of JavaFX that I should probably read up on, but in the meantime, do you have a recommendation for an alternative unit test approach?

I have a class 

    IntegerTextField extends TextField

which restricts inputs to only be numbers. I'd like to unit test this thing. I am currently using TestFX for some GUI testing, and I guess I could just use that to do the testing, but I feel like there should be an easier method. Thoughts?

Comment: I guess it depends a bit on your philosophy of testing. I tend to test assuming that the inner workings of JavaFX are correct (knowing that this is not strictly true, because there are bugs, of course). So I tend to simply unit test the code that is independent of that. In this case, with that philosophy, it would be enough just to  test the filter that you use in your `TextFormatter` (which is still a bit of a pain, but can certainly be done); then I would assume that the text field machinery correctly invokes the filter and processes the result.

Comment: Note in the same vein that calling `appendText(...)` or `insertText(...)` will invoke the filter too, and doesn't rely on a skin etc. So you should be able to use those methods to test.

Comment: More generally, you might also want to look at the [TestFX framework](https://github.com/TestFX/TestFX)

Comment: I did say I was using that a couple comments back :p

Comment: Oh, so you did... sorry - missed that.